# How to check object IDs for deleting in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check my array of "notes" in order to delete the note the user is deleting by comparing the id of each seperate note to the current note's id. Below is my code to do so, once the user clicks yes on the confirmation page to delete the note, it redirects to /delete:

```
router.post('/delete', function(req, res) {
    var id = ObjectID(req.params.id);
    var success = false;

    for (i=0; i < notesCollection.length; i++) {
        if (notesCollection[i].id == id) {
            notesCollection[i] = null;
            success = true;
        }
    }

    if (success == true) {
        res.render("deleteSuccess.jade");
    }
    else {
        res.render("deleteFail.jade");
    }    
});
```

No matter what I do though the note doesn't delete. I believe it's the way I'm checking each seperate id on the line:

```
if (notesCollection[i].id == id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.splice()`instead of setting it to null (which wont remove that element from the array).  Remove the element from the array with `splice`:

```
for (var i=0; i < notesCollection.length; i++) {
        if (notesCollection[i].id == id) {
            notesCollection.splice(i,1);
            success = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

You should also add `var` to declare your loop index `i` so it's not an accidentally global.

Comment: Also should declare the `i` variable as local to the function.

Comment: @jfriend00 your comments are really helping to follow good practices, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I edited in the `var` declaration.  It isn't related to the OP's question, but is a goof in their code and would trigger an error in strict mode.

Comment: @jfriend00 thats an great go form your experience (Y) :)

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, those help! However, the note still isn't being deleted and deleteFail.jade is still being displayed so success is staying as false and therefore the if statement never equals true which it should because one of the notes in notesCollection has to have the same id as the note the user is currently trying to delete

Comment: @bldzrr - then either your data or the id isn't what you think it is.  This code would quite clearly find the id and set `success` if it's in there.  Elemental debugging with `console.log()` statements or stepping through it in the debugger should show you exactly what is going on.  We can't see the actual data.  Only you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove an array item with [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp), like this:

```
array.splice(indexOfElemToRemove, 1);
```

And for optimizing your loop, you should exit when you find the match:

```
for (i = 0; i < notesCollection.length && !success; i++) { //exits when i equals the array's lenght or when success is true
    if (notesCollection[i].id == id) {
        notesCollection.splice(i, 1);
        success = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might create a new problem.  When you remove an item which moves items above it down in the array,  your `for` loop will miss an item and the entire array will not be checked.  If there's only ever one match in the array, this won't be a problem (in which case, you should `break` after finding the match to stop the `for` loop, but if there can be more than one match, this could miss a match.

Comment: Why not just use `break` then to exit the loop?  I was tricked by your non-conventional stopping of the `for` loop and extra condition.  Not as easy to read as it could be.

Comment: because he needs the success variable for later check, so i thought that i could use that also for the loop

Comment: I think you've over thought it and made the code harder to understand.  My opinion.

Comment: Also should declare the `i` variable as local to the function.

Comment: I think that using a break is not so elegant, so when you can avoid it, you should avoid it.. also, considering that the variable name is "success" the for is easy to read.. my opinion

Comment: about the i variable, you're right... i didn't noticed

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to manipulate an array from inside a for loop - that's going to cause problems in JavaScript. You could find the index in the for loop and then delete the item using the index, outside the loop.

```
router.post('/delete', function(req, res) {
    var id = ObjectID(req.params.id);
    var success = false;
    var index = -1;

    for (var i = 0; i < notesCollection.length && !success; i++) {
        if (notesCollection[i].id == id) {
            index = i;
            success = true;
        }
    }

    if (success == true) {
        notesCollection.splice(index,1);
        res.render("deleteSuccess.jade");
    }
    else {
        res.render("deleteFail.jade");
    }    
});
```

Comment: if you choose this way, then the `success` variable is not needed anymore... you can just check `if (i !== -1)`, or you could even declare the `i` outside the `for` and use it later, so you can remove the `index`

Comment: True, though it does still break you out of the `for` loop. If you remove the success variable then you should use `break` to exit the loop when a match is found.

Comment: @lwalden I'm still getting success equal to false and the note isn't being deleted.

Comment: At this point I would want to step through the for loop in the debugger and see what's happening, is id set properly? Is the loop iterrating through the collect as expected?, etc.

Comment: @lwalden I believe I found the problem, notesCollection is a collection within a mongoDB. Is this the same as an array? If not, when it reaches the for loop, the .length of notesCollection is then 0 so the for loop never runs. How can I loop through a mongoDB collection?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with mongoDB but looks like you might be able to use the `.find` method http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/  If not, I'd imagine theres already a stackoverflow answer somewhere for how to either itterate over a mongoDB collection or convert one into an array.